# Logback logging not working

Tags: spring, maven, slf4j, logback

I've a Spring MVC simple addressbook project build with maven. I want to use Logback for logging, but I'm completely new to it; 
first I changed my pom.xml this way:

```
<!-- Spring 3 dependencies -->
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
  <version>${spring.version}</version>
  <exclusions>
    <!--Exclude Commons Logging in favor of SLF4j--> 
    <exclusion>
      <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
      <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
    </exclusion>
  </exclusions>
</dependency>   
<!-- Logging -->
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
  <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
  <version>1.6.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
  <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
  <version>${logback.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
  <artifactId>logback-core</artifactId>
  <version>${logback.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

then I added this lines to my custom Exception DatabaseException:

```
private final static Logger logger = (Logger) LoggerFactory.getLogger(DatabaseException.class);
```

...

```
public DatabaseException(Throwable cause) {
    super(cause);
    logger.log(Level.WARNING, cause.getMessage());
}
```

so that when I rise in other classes this exception the log is able to print to stout some messages, BUT DOES'T WORK, when I run maven on Tomcat it prints only container log [talledContainer] INFO .... etc etc. seems like my logger doesn't exists

Comment: i think the title is missleading

Comment: you need to configure the logger. this is in most cases done in a xml or a properties

Comment: Please consolidate the two questions, and please don't post duplicates. It becomes quite difficult for people to help you.

Answer (score 2):

To your DatabaseException make it work, your DatabaseException should be like this:

```
package org.myorg.myapp;

import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

public class DatabaseException extends Exception {

  private final static Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(DatabaseException.class);

  public DatabaseException(Throwable cause) {
    super(cause);
    logger.warn(cause.getMessage());
  }
}
```

Also, you need to include jcl-over-slf4j dependency in your pom.xml.

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
  <artifactId>jcl-over-slf4j</artifactId>
  <version>1.6.1</version>
  <scope>runtime</scope>
</dependency>
```

I would recommend reading the reference documentation (Using SLF4J section).
http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/overview.html

Hope this helps.

Comment: Adding jlc dependency and importing in my class slf4j.logger and slf4j.LoggerFactory it works fine

Answer (score 1):

You have not mentioned anything about **logback.xml**. You should create one under **src/main/resources** folder.